# Hide navigation bar but keep back button

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using xamarin forms to build android app, and I use navigation page to navigate between pages. I'd like to hide the bar but keep the back button, because I have some else controls to put in the top area. I used [HasNavigationBar](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.HasNavigationBarProperty/) and [HasBackButton](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage.HasBackButtonProperty/) for this, but it looks the back button cannot be restored if the bar is hidden. Is there anyway to show the back button?

XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="CH.AdDetailPage"
         NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
         NavigationPage.HasBackButton="True"
         NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle="Back" Title="AdDetail">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Ad Detail Pages!" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

When `HasNavigationBar=True, and HasBackButton=True`:
[image]
When `HasNavigationBar=True, and HasBackButton=False`:
[image]
Both above works.

But when `HasNavigationBar=False, and HasBackButton=True`: it does not work.
[image]

Comment: The back button lives within the navigation bar...  Hide the nav. bar. and create you own button and place it where you want and have it perform a Finish()

Comment: @SushiHangover is there no way to let the system embed a software back button?

Comment: There is, within the navigation bar ;-)

Comment: Okay, I see. I wanted to use system button because I have multiple pages to do the same behavior.

Comment: Either use the navigation bar with `HasBackButton` or turn off the bar and add your own "navigation bar"/"back button" in your own style to the page.

Comment: Ok will do that.

Comment: @SushiHangover is there anyway to add additional controls to the system navigation bar

Comment: You can use a Page's ToolbarItems: check out how this guide adds All None buttons to the nav/toolbar: https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/controls/multiselect/

Answer (score 0):

Back button is a part of navigation bar. You can not show it without showing the navbar.

your only way is to create your back button and assign command with NavigationService.GoBack ...